# Performance tuning/diagnotics help needed... (12.04LTS 64bit, LVM, & LUKS)

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, performance, lvm, luks

I just performed a fresh install of 12.04LTS 64-bit, using the alternate CD, with LVM and LUKS. Install went fine but I've noticed a few quirks and was hoping for some pointers/suggestions from the community.

---

**Issues:**

1. On boot, before entering encryption pass phrase, I get a message "ERROR: No video mode activated" (Everything seems to work fine though)
2. I've got a noticeable but inconsistent "lag/delay" in the launcher/nautilus with the new load. The delay can sometimes be as much as 5+ seconds. Things like the compiz cube/rotator work very fast so I don't think it's a graphics issue.

NOTE: Neither of these issues were present in my original 32bit std install (using the disc from the "Ubuntu Unleashed 2012 edition" book.)

**Question:**

How do I get rid of the boot error (I'm guessing it's a config issue with grub)?

What would be the best way to further diagnose the "lag" that I'm experiencing?

- I'm not sure if it's an issue with 64-bit Precise (though I seen several posts reporting the issue with no solutions) or full disk encryption.  I know my CPU supports AES-NI, how do I determine if it's enabled/configured properly?

---

My system:

- HP Z210 SFF Workstation
- Intel Xeon E3-1245 quad-core, hyperthreaded
- Integrated Intel HD 3000 Graphics (registering as "Intel Sandybridge Server" after installing mesa-utils)
- 8GB RAM
- 500GB HDD (LVM & LUKS configured using the wizard on the entire drive)

**top:**

```
top - 13:37:05 up  2:12,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.21, 0.21
Tasks: 210 total,   1 running, 209 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8063752k total,  4227732k used,  3836020k free,    34392k buffers
Swap:  8269820k total,    53548k used,  8216272k free,  3418876k cached
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a known bug. There are suggested work arounds on the bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802

Most common is:

```
Commenting out GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET in /etc/default/grub works for me.

GRUB_DEFAULT=GRUB_SAVED_DEFAULT
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_TERMINAL=console

GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
```

I do not know the problem with nautilus, but this question has been asked with no obvious solution either. I doubt it has to do with either LVM or LUKS.

[Nautilus is really slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165627/nautilus-is-really-slow)

[Nautilus is extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60227/nautilus-is-extremely-slow)

The most common problem is a network share (samba) that is not mounted.

Perhaps running nautilus from the command line might show an error of some kind.

Comment: Looked into the other posts you listed. No luck there. I found no symlinks in root to network share (didn't expect any as this is a fresh install) and no assistive tech features are enabled. I'll keep looking. Thanks again!

Comment: Best of luck, I did not see and obvious solution to your nautilus problem either. Hope somebody can help you.